# how to access check box of a place holder

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web, checkbox

I am working on a web app using ASP.net C#.
I have created check boxes using HTML string builder in my page load.

```
StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
 html.Append(" <input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input' runat='server' id='check1"'>");
```

In onClick function, how can I access the id of my checkbox which I have placed in html placeholder?

Comment: Is your "onClick" function Javascript?

Comment: You cannot add `runat=server` to a string and expect it to work. That is not how Webforms works. You will need "real" dynamic Controls.